# Data is not appearing in google search console performance report for new website?

Tags: google-search-console

Today, I hosted a new website, for google search console and went to webmaster tools and added a new property `http://subsite.example.com` and added verification for this site successfully.  I have already enabled google search console in google analytics on that site.

The problem is, why is data not showing in the performance report?  Please give me any solution for getting data to help me and what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Google Search Console takes time to reflect the reports. After adding and verifying, give few days time to get the reports.

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm you have the correct version of the site verified and the correct version associated with the Google Analytics property.

This means if your site is https://subsite.example.com, you must verify and connect https://subsite.example.com

Google sees sites running http, https, or with or without www as different sites.

Search Console is also 2 days behind in displaying data. Finally, make sure you don't have any segments enabled in the GA Search Console view as data may not show.

Answer (score 0):

To make @Rob's answer clearer.  You may have already verified the main site before.
But you need to verify the subsite as well.

New sites can take days to weeks to get going.  If `site:subsite_url` in Google search on a browser shows the subsite, then it is indexed correctly. Just wait